# Spark + Kafka: How to join kafka stream with RDBMS

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Requirement: I have different microservices producing data to Kafka. I want to collect the information, do aggregation and build tables for the reporting.

The building new tables for reporting will require me to read data from Kafka, compare it with existing fact tables and create/update new roes in the database.

What I was thinking was to use Spark Streaming to read from Kafka topics and have the joins with RDBMS Database.

Looking for help to understand the best way to have the joins.

Comment: I would suggest trying structured streaming and joining those dataframes with ones pulled from jdbc connection

Comment: The issue is the DB might have records in millions but the Kafka might have the records for few entries only. Loading the whole table from DB seems to be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC Connector and CDC more efficient ways to load/upload data through Database. We can follow the below steps:

1. Create CDC or JDBC Kafka source connector to load all data from the RDBMS table(user)  into Kafka

[Please refer here JDBC Connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc/)

2. Create 2 Kafka stream from both Kafka topic
3. Join using Kafka Stream join and aggregation

[Please refer here Kafka Stream join](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html)

4. a. Update back to DB using custom Java JDBC
   or

   b. try to publish updated data to a new topics and use the JDBC sink connector to update back to the RDBMS DB table.

Comment: On Step 1 Loading whole data in my case millions of records doesn't sound scalable

Comment: Kafka is for large scale data ....and easily scalable based on demand...

Comment: I ended up writing up a spark streaming job and a scheduled job. Spark Streaming job was responsible for reading the Kafka topics and updating the fact tabes and spark schedule job is responsible for reading from the data warehouse and updating reporting tables. Not sure it is the best way of doing but it solved my problem